# Maven dependency plugin downloads POM instead of tar.gz

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have two modules:

```
  module 1: builds as .tar.gz with assembly plugin (type declared as 'pom' in its pom.xml)

  module 2: needs to depend on the .tar.gz from the module above but always pulls the pom from the nexus instead.
```

Is there any trick?   I see my .tar.gz on my Nexus correctly, it's just module 2 never goes for it, always just downloading the POM.

Comment: How do you declare the dependency? Do you specify the type?

Comment: yes, I did have .tar.gz.   I did not also have the classifier from the assembly plugin job that built it.   This was not easy to pinpoint until I saw the nexus metadata xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue.   If I look in the metadata of the nexus (maven-metadata.xml)

I see my .tar.gz with a classifier tag from the maven assembly plugin id (the one from the external assembly xml).

I had this in the dependency plugin config, but not lower in the actual dependency section of my pom.   Once I also added the classifier tag here, it all works as expected.

Comment: Is there a way to do it via mvn dependency:get command without pom?